# How can I apply for the long term French Visa from Italy, when my permesso is expired and waiting for renewal?

Tags: visa, france, italy

I am currently residing in Italy and my permit stay is expired. I am renewing it so I have the renewal receipt. I got a job offer in France and now I have to apply for a visa from the French consulate in Italy.

I need to have a valid permit stay in Italy to apply for the visa in Rome, I thought of asking for a temporary permit stay in Italy (permesso di soggiorno provvisorio).

Can I apply for the long term visa with the temporary permit stay in the French consulate in Rome? Would it be a problem in my visa application?